# Will Allah do miracles for us in our time?

Tags: practical-islam, miracles

We know that before Allah did miracles for his slaves. Like Story of Zakariyah (Zechariah) PBUH.
He asked Allah for child in very old age, But Allah made miracles and gave him a child. So is this even possible today. Like if a old man ask for child, will allah give him?

So my question is if a person makes a dua that is only possible by Allah's miracle, Will there be a possibility that his dua will be accepted And allah will do miracle for him or The doors of miracles have shut down?

Comment: I guess an answer somewhat depends on how you define a miracle. For example about 30 years ago while went to school one day while waiting in front of the school portal some stupid people started throwing stones over it in the crowd of students waiting on the other side in order to leave at a moment I noticed that my shoelaces were open and bent down and a huge rock felt that was thrown at the wall felt down six inches from where I was standing before so if I didn't do this movement to fix my laces I might not be alive now. But somehow Allah saved me.

Answer (score -2):

The miracle is ourselves and the earth that we stand upon. Men, being forgetful, forgets this; it's only when we see with the eyes of a child to whom everything is new, that we see the wonder that is all this earth, and ourselves.

This is what is meant by when the Qu'ran describes Allah as al-Khaliq, the Creator and as al-Mussawir,  the Crafter and al-Hafiz, the Maintainor and the Provider.

As one philosopher put it: he marvelled at the moral law within and the stars above in the firmament of the night sky.

And Allah knows best.

**edit**

@Yusha: And if you read what I'm saying carefully, you'll see that I'm saying that your question is credulous ...

Comment: My question was not that, read it again. I basically mean will allah do miracles in our time as he did before. So it means is it okay to hope for something that is impossible to us.